# iPhone 5 storage

Tags: iphone

In settings, my iPhone 5 shows I have 327.9 MB of free space remaining. However, when I open iTunes on my laptop I see 2.29 GB of unused storage space showing on the usage bar at the bottom of my screen. Which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

iTunes does not see content downloaded for offline listening on iPhone. For example, content downloaded from Spotify will not appear to take up iTunes storage but will take up iPhone storage and iCloud storage if you are using iCloud to back up content and access content across multiple devices.